# How is the type resolved in this statement

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers

Reading "Write Yourself a Scheme in 48 hours" and am confused on this page https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Write_Yourself_a_Scheme_in_48_Hours/Adding_Variables_and_Assignment by:

```
getVar :: Env -> String -> IOThrowsError LispVal
getVar envRef var  =  do env <- liftIO $ readIORef envRef
                         maybe (throwError $ UnboundVar "Getting an unbound variable" var)
                               (liftIO . readIORef)
                               (lookup var env)
```

I'm not entirely clear how the type is resolved. Here's my reasoning:

`envRef` is of type `IORef [(String, IORef LispVal)]`, so `readIORef envRef` is of type `IO [(String, IORef LispVal)]`.

Now `LiftIO` is defined at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-IO-Class.html as being of type `liftIO :: IO a -> m a` and is implemented at https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/src/Control-Monad-Error.html#ErrorT. So `liftIO $ readIORef envRef` returns `m [(String, IORef LispVal)]` for some monad m (which doesn't matter because we just use `<-` on it straight away so ignore the monad wrapper) [1].

This means env is `[(String, IORef LispVal)]`, so `lookup var env` is `Maybe IORefLispVal`. For the Just branch of the maybe, `liftIO . readIORef` will be `m LispVal`, again for some monad m. Given the whole function returns an `IOThrowsError LispVal` (which is just an `ErrorT LispError IO LispVal` i.e. `IO Either LispError LispVal`), so m must be an `IOThrowsError` [2].

Now if there are different monad transformers in place, I guess that there could be more than one liftIO with a different type signature in scope. Is this actually the case and if so, to what extent is the chain of reasoning above representative of how Haskell actually determines the types? I'm not happy with the reasoning at [1] or [2], so there's a secondary question of how the monad for liftIO is determined. And finally for a do statement how does do know what monad it's in? Is this determined by the first monad after the `<-`? Or some other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have `liftIO $ readIORef envRef`, with the type `MonadIO m => m [(String, IORef LispVal)]`, the `m` certainly matters!  It can only be a monad that implements the `MonadIO` typeclass, and it can not be just ignored.  It has to be the same monad as returned by the `maybe ...` statement.  In general, when working with do notation, all statements inside of a given block have to have the same monad, so you could do

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Testing"
    x <- getLine
    putStrLn x
```

But you **can't** do

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Testing"
    x <- Just "Doesn't work!"
    putStrLn x
```

Because `IO` and `Maybe` are not in the same monad!  On top of that, `main` is specified to have type `IO ()`, so you can't have any opportunity to return something other than an `IO` action.

If you're unsure about what type this could be generalized too, I would recommend loading it into GHCi and checking it without a type signature specified.  I believe that it would end up being something along the lines of

```
getVar :: (Eq a, MonadIO m, MonadError LispVal m) => IORef [(a, IORef LispVal)] -> a -> m b
```

because `liftIO $ readIORef envRef` and `liftIO . readIORef` means that the monad must be an instance of `MonadIO`, in order to perform the `lookup`, you need your keys to be an instance of `Eq`, and the `throwError $ UnboundVar "..."` means that it has to be an instance of `MonadError LispVal`.  There is nothing that concretes the rest of the signature to return `LispVal`s, or be the specific monad you're using of `IOThrowsError`.

Comment: Thanks. So the return of the do clause must match the return type of the statement, which means both of the `liftIO` need to return `IOThrowsError` values (as one is the return of the do clause and the other has <- applied to it). But the first `liftIO` is operating on a `IO [(String, IORef LispVal)]`, so I don't see what its result type could be.

Comment: The type of `liftIO` is `MonadIO m => IO a -> m a`.  Since your `IOThrowsError a` type is just `ErrorT LispVal IO a`, and `MonadIO m => ErrorT e m a` is an instance of `MonadIO`, you can constrain `liftIO`'s type to be `liftIO :: IO a -> ErrorT LispVal IO a`.